# How Does Redux deals with deeply nested Models?

Tags: redux

How does Redux deals with a deeply nested leaf Model change? meaning, I'm dispatching a change event from a leaf all they way up to it's reducer handle and I don't want to broadcast a change event to the whole tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Redux all actions are always dispatched to the whole reducer tree. This makes it easy to handle the same action from different reducers without them knowing about each other. This is useful in large apps where different people work on different reducers—they can handle the same actions without having merge conflicts all the time.

In the vey unlikely case you are *really* having a performance problem because of this global dispatch (profile first! usually it's not a problem), you can use [redux-ignore](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-ignore) for fine-grained control over which reducers receive which actions. This gives you better performance in edge cases, but you sacrifice the simplicity of the default model, so only do this if you profiled the app and the results show that this is necessary.